# How am I to understand C++20 parameter copies in coroutines according to the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

[[dcl.fct.def]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#13) says the following about the copies of coroutine parameters that live on the coroutine frame:

> When a coroutine is invoked, after initializing its parameters ([[expr.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.call)), a copy is created for each coroutine parameter. For a parameter of type *cv* `T`, the copy is a variable of type *cv* `T` […]
>
> [*Note 2*: An original parameter object is never a const or volatile object ([[basic.type.qualifier]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.type.qualifier)). — end note]

I don't think I quite understand the part about const/volatile qualifications, because the two lines seem to contradict each other, or at least maybe the first one contains unnecessary information. It seems to be saying that a parameter of type `const Foo` would result in a `const Foo` on the coroutine frame, but then the second line seems to say that the parameter can't be `const Foo` in the first place. It doesn't help that [[basic.type.qualifier]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.type.qualifier) doesn't mention parameters at all.

What's going on with the wording here? What is it trying to tell me exactly? Which part of the standard says a parameter can't be const or volatile?

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#5.sentence-4

Comment: This is trying to say that the initialization of the copy from an xvalue of type `T` (in the [...] part of the quote) can modify the source without risking undefined behavior, even if the parameter is declared const.